# Unique ID issue when using spatial weights matrix with Hot Spot Analysis (Getis-Ord Gi*)

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-statistics

I'm trying to follow along with an ArcGIS tutorial, and I'm running into an issue since I'm using my own data instead of the tutorial data.

[This is the tutorial](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/analytics/case-studies/analyzing-crashes-2-pro-workflow.htm#:%7E:text=Identify%20crash%20hot%20spots%20on%20the%20road%20network) and I'm working on the 'Identify crash hot spots on the road network' section. I have to create my own spatial weights file, which they discuss [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/analytics/case-studies/analyzing-crashes-2-pro-workflow.htm#:%7E:text=to%200.25.-,Dive%2Din%3A,-Hot%20spot%20analysis).

The issue is the network spatial weights file is created based on a point feature class (the crash locations) using a unique ID field I created by copying the OBJECTID field. When I try to run the Hotspot Analysis (Getis-Ord Gi*) on the line feature class, it says there is an mismatch with the Unique ID field.

"000949: The input feature class does not contain the Unique ID field () that the input spatial weights matrix () was constructed with." is the error I get.

I guess I'm not sure how to create a spatial weights file based on a point feature class and then use it to run a hot spot analysis on a line feature class like they did in the tutorial.